# Include php file in wordpress generated page

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha

I'm working on registration form and use a simple captcha php script to generate captcha image.

This is the html code used to display the captcha image on the page

```
<img id="img" src="captcha.php">
```

Everything worked fine on the static version of the page, but the image doesn't show on Wordpress generated page.

Is it possible to display my captcha image in Wordpress page without using any plugins ?

EDIT: I'm adding a bit more of my code

My **page.php** file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-left-outer">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-left">
            <img id="img" src="'.home_url().'/captcha.php"> <-- Added this line to test if captcha will display from page.php file -->
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-right">
          <!-- Archive Side Navigation -->
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- /.row -->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The code I input in the textbox in Wordpress dashboard

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
      <label for="InputName">Παρακαλούμε, εισάγετε CAPTCHA</label>        
      <img id="img" src="'.home_url().'/captcha.php">
      <input id="captcha1" class="form-control" name="captcha" type="text" required>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a path problem to me. I shouldn't see why it wouldn't work. Just make sure that all your Wordpress files are `.php` extensions also. Check for errors too.

Comment: Is `<img id="img" src="captcha.php">` in the generated html code?

Comment: Please provide details about your environment. How is the registration form generated by WP? Do you know about WP templates? Do you know about WP hooks?

Comment: @Fred -ii- The captcha.php file is located in the root of my template folder. It shouldn't be a path problem.

Comment: @PaulH Yes I can see this snippet when I load the page.
The page with form is generated by Wordpress through page.php file in my template directory. Yes, I know about templates, I'm using my own custom template. I'm not familiar with hooks though.

Comment: All I can say is: "check for errors". There could be something wrong somewhere. That is beyond our control here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WP uses .htaccess to rewrite, you should not use a relative path as in
`src="captcha.php"`, but an absolute path like
`src="http://www.example.com/wp/captcha.php"` or
`src="/wp/captcha.php"`

You will have to adapt the paths above to your configuration.

WP knows where your site is located, so to be independent, use something like:

```
<?php
echo '<img id="img" src="' . home_url() . '/captcha.php">';
```

or

```
<img id="img" src="<? php echo home_url() ?>/captcha.php">
```

---

Edit:
`<?php` will only work if in a plugin or template. If your `html` code is only in a WP Widget text Content, the PHP will not be parsed for security reasons.

Comment: This is how the html snippet looks like after page is loaded
`<img id="img" src="'home_url().'/captcha.php">`
The url does not seem to be resolved into a path.
Perhaps the problem is that my snippet is not included inside header.php or page.php file, but in the text box when creating new page though Wordpress dashboard ??

Comment: Sorry, corrected typo in my answer. Can you provide more context, the lines around your snippet?

Comment: Okay, I managed to get captcha to display with the following snippet
`<img id="img" src="<?php echo home_url() ?>/captcha.php">`
But it only works when I include it inside my page.php file.
Perhaps the page generated by wordpress is in html format not php, hence the path is not resolved.

EDIT: I want to have control on where to display my captcha on the page, so I need it to work when added from the dashboard page generator.

Comment: Indeed, WP will not execute php statements in text box of a Post. That would be a security issue. So in that case, use src="http://www.example.com/wp/captcha.php" or
src="/wp/captcha.php" (adapt the path to your configuration) as in the first part of the answer text above.

Comment: Yes ! That did it. I used the path that was resolved by `<?php echo home_url() ?>/captcha.php"` from the source code after the page loaded and pasted it in the text box.

You should change `echo home_url` to `echo home_url()` in your last snippet and I will accept your answer. Thanks !